# Using the past perfect in a context

Tags: meaning-in-context, past-perfect, grammaticality-in-context, sequence-of-tenses, conversation

Is the following make sense from the context side and the grammatical one. ??

She was the prime minister :

1- she had held this post and she had remained in it for 10 years.

2- she had been in this post for 10 years.

Comment: (1) is an unnecessarily convoluted way of expressing the idea.

Comment: @Kate Bunting   Thank you .But, is it because it is grammatically wrong or just weak expression ?!

Comment: No, if it had been grammatically wrong I would have said so. But if you simply want to state for how long someone had been PM, (2) is all you need.

Comment: "is the following make sense" is not correct, you should say: "does the following make sense".